# how to deselect all in RichTextBox before selecting newly found text?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following function which selects and highlights text.

```
if (startIndex >= 0)
            {

                FormsRtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                var selectedTextLength = findContext.TextToFind.Length;

                FormsRtb.Select(startIndex, selectedTextLength);
                _previoslyFoundTextIndex = startIndex + selectedTextLength;
            }
```

EveryTime new text is found I need to deselect and unhighlight previously found text.

I tried to do this code snippet before selecting new text, but id did not help.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

```
    FormsRtb.SelectAll();
    FormsRtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
    FormsRtb.DeselectAll();
```

Comment: It should work, try `FormRtb.Select(0, 0);` after your `DeselectAll()` statement.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, text is not highlighted anymore

Comment: _unfortunately it does not work, text is not highlighted anymore_ Um, isn't that what you wanted???

Comment: I wanted previous text to be unselected but newly found selected again, but now none text is highlighted, both previous one and newly found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you are doing the selection itself not quite right: After

0) de-highlighting you should

1) set the `SelctionStart` and the `SelectionLength` then

2) set the `SelectionBackColor`.

You should **not** change the `SelectionBackColor` of the RTB itself (ie without setting the selection first) all the time..!

```
if (startIndex >= 0)
{
    FormsRtb.SelectAll();                    // first we un-highlight
    FormsRtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;   // probably FormsRtb.BackColor is better?
    FormsRtb.DeselectAll();

    var selectedTextLength = findContext.TextToFind.Length;

    FormsRtb.Select(startIndex, selectedTextLength);     // now we select..
    FormsRtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;  //..and only then we highlight

    _previoslyFoundTextIndex = startIndex + selectedTextLength;
}
```